# .Net User Login Program

Tags: mysql, .net

I'm wondering if there exists a pre-build application to handle user logins and permission structure for a .net application.

This would be to manage clients logging in and what data they can see.

Essentially I would like to buy a framework instead of building one ourselves.

Does something like this exists, if so do you either have any examples or suggestions on what to look for?

thanks,

Comment: Just to elaborate an answer forward your needs. Do you plan to use an ASP.NET Web application or a WinForms/WPF application?

Comment: it would be an ASP.net application. We would need to have the data controlled by groups and roles, and limit each of those combinations to a subsection of data and application features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would develop my own custom membership provider and use the ASP.NET membership service. If your goal is to create a framework for your applications, the effort is suitable.

There is a nice article showing the implementation of a custom provider, even using the new MVC technologies.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

There is also a programmers exchange topic about what we are talking abour:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104268/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-writting-a-net-custom-membership-provider

Let me know any issues that you have.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like we'll have to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ASP.net membership & role services outside an ASP.net app.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2006/12/16/asp-net-2-0-membership-role-management-out-of-asp-net-context.aspx

Comment: We'd tried this previously and not had great experiences, it seems to have a lot hiccups. Have you had success with this?

Comment: Yes, it's widely used and plenty of tools and documentation to use it.